# Check key value exists in array object or not, if not exists push object inside array and short array with same key value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with objects like

```
var array = [{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:1},
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:10:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:5},
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:3},
...
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 23:55:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:8},
];
```

where I need to check for each interval time with 5 minute.Suppose my start and end time are

```
var start = 'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)';
var end = 'Thu Jul 27 2017 23:55:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)';
```

If any interval data is missing then, I need to push that object with given time interval as key 'x' and 'y' as 0. Means my output must look like this-

```
var output= [{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:1},
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:0},
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:10:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:5},
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:3},
...
{x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 23:55:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:8},
];
```

where missing object {x:'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:05:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)',y:0}, has been added.
What I have tried.

```
var start = 'Thu Jul 27 2017 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)';
var end = 'Thu Jul 27 2017 23:55:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)';
 var interval = 300000;
 //loop through every 5 minute interval
 for(var dt = start;dt<end;dt = new Date(dt.getTime()+ interval)){
    if( !lookup( dt , array ) ) {
      array .push({
        x: dt,
        y: 0
      });
    }
 }
 console.log("Unsorted output is" + array);// result

function lookup( name,arr ) {
  for(var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    if( arr[ i ].key === name )
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

As far as from my side of logic I see everything is OK but I cannot see missing interval added. Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are your dates stored as Date or as a string?

Comment: @baklazan Is Date.

Answer (score 0):

**Why don't you try converting the objects into millisecs and comparing that...**

the code snippet should be a bit simpler and give you the gist of what i'm talking about.

In this example I created an array that holds the millisec value of each date object. It would be just as easy to loop through the actual object and use the `getTime()` method to convert it to millisecs on the fly although untested...this is likely slower than pushing the converted integer in one go.

The only challenge this leaves you with is ordering and whether you need the dates ordered or not...with this method it simply pushes the new values into the object at the end.

**NOTE CODE IS  UNTESTED--ITS JUST TO GIVE A GENREAL IDEA**

```js
//create an array in tandem with your objects array that holds the millisec value

var millisecArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //loop through the existing date object array
 millisecArray.push(array[i]['x'].getTime()); //and push its millisec value into the new array
}

var start = startObj.getTime(); //gets the time in millisecs
var end = endObj.getTime(); //gets the time in millisecs
var interval = 300000;
var newDateObj = new Date();

 //loop through every 5 minute interval
 for(var current = start; current < end; current = current + interval;){ //keep looping until current is 5 minutes smaller than end
    if( !lookup( current , millisecArray ) ) {
      array.push({
        x: newDateObj.setTime(current),
        y: 0
      });
      millisecArray.push(current);
    }
 }

function lookup( name,arr ) {
  for(var j = 0; i < arr.length; j++) {
    if( arr[ j ] === name )
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```